# How to register a new user using CloudBoost.io in Android

Tags: android, cloudboost

I am trying to use register a new user to CloudBoost and the docs show that this is how you register a new user:

```
CloudUser user = new CloudUser();
user.set("username", "my_username");
user.set("password", "my_solid_password");
user.set("email", "email@sample.com");
user.signUp();
```

When I try to do this:

```
CloudUser user = new CloudUser();
user.set("email", email);
user.set("password", password);
user.signUp();
```

`user.set("email")` and `user.set("password")` are both underlined with error and it says `unhandled exception: io.cloudboost.CloudException` and the parenthesis on `user.signUp()` is also underlined and says that is needs a `CloudUserCallback`. Obviously their documentation is not up to date. Does someone know how this can be fixed?